# How to set center using external lat, lng?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've built an application that draws an address from a data base. I've used geocoder (https://www.npmjs.com/package/geocoder) to get the lat and lng of the address and now wish that everytime I hit a button that pulls the address, it will update the map to zoom to that address and centre. Can this be done if I'm pulling the address external to the maps component?

Here's my map component so far:

```
    const MapWithASearchBox = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDYwerCGhOnkM1sNHmSrckp8D1o9hY3mZ4&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount(){

    },
    componentWillMount() {
      const refs = {}

      this.setState({

        bounds: null,
        center: {
          lat: -35.015742, lng: 138.520858
        },
        markers: [],
        onMapMounted: ref => {
          refs.map = ref;
        },
        onIdle: () => {
          this.setState({
            center: fullPos,
          })
        },
        onBoundsChanged: () => {
          this.setState({
            bounds: refs.map.getBounds(),
            center: refs.map.getCenter(),
          })
        },
        onSearchBoxMounted: ref => {
          console.log("s. mounted");
          refs.searchBox = ref;
        },
        onPlacesChanged: () => {
          console.log("places changed");
          console.log(refs.searchBox)
          console.log(refs)
          const places = refs.searchBox.getPlaces();
          console.log(places);
          const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

          places.forEach(place => {
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport)
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location)
            }
          });
          const nextMarkers = places.map(place => ({
            position: place.geometry.location,
          }));
          const nextCenter = _.get(nextMarkers, '0.position', this.state.center);

          this.setState({
            center: nextCenter,
            markers: nextMarkers,
          });
          // refs.map.fitBounds(bounds);
        },

      })
    },
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    ref={props.onMapMounted}
    defaultZoom={20}
    center={props.center}
    onBoundsChanged={props.onBoundsChanged}
    mapTypeId={google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE}
    panControl={true}
    scrollwheel={false}
  >
    <SearchBox
      ref={props.onSearchBoxMounted}
      bounds={props.bounds}
      controlPosition={google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT}
      onPlacesChanged={props.onPlacesChanged}
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Customized your placeholder"
        value={fullAdd}
        style={{
          boxSizing: `border-box`,
          border: `1px solid transparent`,
          width: `240px`,
          height: `32px`,
          marginTop: `27px`,
          padding: `0 12px`,
          borderRadius: `3px`,
          boxShadow: `0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)`,
          fontSize: `14px`,
          outline: `none`,
          textOverflow: `ellipses`,
        }}
      />
    </SearchBox>
    {props.isMarkerShown && (
      <Marker position={fullPos} />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
);
```

Where fullPos is the lat, lng variable I've been playing around with in different areas in hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

> pulling the address external to the maps component

Not sure you mean **Passing the new address from outside the component to it as a prop** then, maybe you can use **ComponentWillUpdate** and make some beautiful conditions (to avoid bad endless loops) and also to check only if the passedAddressProp is changed, then maybe you can do something like: `this.setState({center: passedAddressProp})`

**or**

most likely obviously, you mean by it **I get this address somewhere super far from this component so there's no chance they can communicate**, then maybe the solution lies in redux/mobx (whichever you prefere/use) and when the address is changed, you can fire an action with the new address, and this component listens on this part of the state, also with some beautiful condition inside componentWillUpdate, you can change the this.state.center when this global part of the state changes.